# How to fix this expression

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to print multiple `*` based on rating value. In Javascript console `Array(10).join('*')` produces 10 stars. When using it in Angularjs view, this expression is not evaluated. Am I missing something?

```
<div data-ng-controller="SkillsController">
 <ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="skill in skills">{{skill.name}} - {{Array(skill.rating).join('*')}}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

App.js

```
app.controller('SkillsController', function($scope){
    $scope.skills = [
        { name: 'Ruby', rating: 5 },
        { name: 'Java', rating: 10}
    ];
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array is not part of the $scope. You can do the following in your controller.

```
app.controller('SkillsController', function($scope){
    $scope.skills = [
        { name: 'Ruby', rating: 5 },
        { name: 'Java', rating: 10}
    ];

    $scope.Array = Array; 
});
```

I would however do this transformation in a filter or directive.

```
app.filter('stars', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return Array(input).join('*');
  };
});
```

And then

```
{{skill.rating | stars}}
```

Comment: I agree. Make a directive for this :) <div skills-rating="skill" />

Comment: Brilliant. Is it possible to limit the scope of filter to `SkillsController`?

Comment: Also, I noticed that the number of stars returned is always `N-1`

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the best way to create a method in $scope of controller to get rating transformed as you wish. From this method call another method placed in service. Thus, you'll separate business logic from presentation logic and from view.

So, View

```
<div data-ng-controller="SkillsController">
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="skill in skills">{{skill.name}} - {{ getRating(skill) }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('SkillsController', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.skills = [
        { name: 'Ruby', rating: 5 },
        { name: 'Java', rating: 10}
    ];
    $scope.getRating = function (skill) {
        return myService.transformRatings(skill.rating);
    }
});
```

Service:

```
app.service('myService', function(){
    return {
        transformRatings: function (stars) {
            return Array(stars).join('*');
        }
    }
});
```